# OpenCPU and multi-page plots

Tags: r, pdf, opencpu

I'm trying to capture a multi-plot pdf from a function. In R, this gives me a three page PDF:

```
pdf(file='test.pdf', onefile=TRUE)
lapply(1:3, 'plot')
dev.off()
```

Using OpenCPU:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6977/ocpu/library/base/R/lapply -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"X":[1,2,3], "FUN":"plot"}'
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/R/.val
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/graphics/1
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/graphics/2
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/graphics/3
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/stdout
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/source
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/console
/ocpu/tmp/x0dc3dad0/info
```

I can get any of the individual pages as a single-page PDF file, but not as one combined file.

Two possible work-arounds, not without their share of problems:

1. Use `par(mfrow)`, `layout()`, or a similar mechanism, though this will create a monster image in the end (I'm dealing with more than three images in my code).
2. Use `tempfile`, create an Rmd file on-the-fly, return the filename in the session (have not tested this yet), and use OpenCPU's processing of Rmd files. Unfortunately, this now uses LaTeX's geometries and page numbering (workarounds exist for this).

Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. OpenCPU captures graphics using `evaluate` which stores each graphic individually. The API itself doesn't support combining multiple graphics within a single file. I would personally do this sort of `PDF` post processing in the application layer (i.e. with non-R tools), but perhaps it would be useful to support this in the API.

Some suggestions:

- Any file that your R function/script saves to the *working directory* (i.e. `getwd()`) will also become available through the API. So one thing you could do is in your R code manually create your combined `pdf` file and save it to the working directory and then download it through opencpu.
- Graphics are actually `recordedPlot` objects, and besides `png`, `pdf` and `svg`, you can also retrieve the graphic as `rds` or `rda`. So you could write an R function that downloads the `recordedPlot` object from the API and then prints it. Not sure if that would be helpful in your use case.

Comment: That's what I suspected, and since I'm not fluent in `recordedPlot`, I wanted to make sure. I also suspected the *working directory* thing as well, which is why I think the `tempfile()` and Rmd thing could work as at times. This also explains why graphs that "show" well (i.e., spacing of text/elements is calculated) while testing do not always present as well through this mechanism.
(Post-processing of multiple PDF files with non-R tools would rely on having the appropriate tools on the client computer, not something on which I can rely.)
Thanks.